# convert list comprehension into loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert list comprehension into for loop.
`lst = [ x**2 for x in [x**2 for x in range(11)] ]`

I tried with below code

```
lst = []
for x in range(1):
  for x in range(11):
    lst.append(x**4)
print lst
```

But this does not match with `x**2` and `x**2`. In my code, there is no `x**2` twice

```
lst = []
for x in range(1):
   for x in range(11):
       lst.append(x**4)
print lst
```

can someone help with for loop where `x**2` appears twice?

Comment: Your print statement is a statement, not a function.  Are you using Python 2?  Unless you have a very good reason to use Py2, switch to Py3.  Py2 is at end-of-life.  Now as for the output you want, do you want `lst` to equal `[0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000]`?  Because that's the answer I get with your list comprehension and with your multi-line code in Python3.

Comment: You would need to build an intermediate list of squares with your first loop, then loop over it and square it again in a second loop.

Comment: @darshanshah I've updated my answer to use two for loop and two `x**2`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57441146/3091398)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,

```
lst = []
for x in range(11):
    x = x**2
    lst.append(x**2)
```

This is same as,

```
for x in range(11):
    lst.append(x**4)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000]
```

If you are very particular that you need to use nested `for` loop and `x**2` twice then you can try the below code,

```
lst = []
for x in range(11):
    lst.append(x**2) # appends squared of x to the lst 
    for x in [lst[-1]]: # loops (one iteration) using the last inserted item of the list `lst`
        lst[-1] = x**2 # performs squared operation on the x value again and update the value in lst
print lst
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000]
```

See all in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/FreeDelayedGeneric).

Answer (score 1):

In the list comprehension, the inner comprehension's `x` is distinct from the variable with the same name in the outer scope. When you unroll this, the variables are in the same scope, so they can't use the same name.

```py
lst = []
for y in range(1):
  for x in range(11):
    lst.append(x**4)
print(lst)
```

But of course, you don't need two loops - a loop over a static list with a single element is entirely pointless.

If you insist on having `x**2` twice, that can be done too, of course:

```
lst = []
for x in range(11):
    x = x ** 2
    lst.append(x**2)
```

But both unrolling the comprehension and breaking up `x**2` looks to me like unnecessary changes. This is simple enough that it should be understandable to any competent programmer; maybe add a comment if something seems particularly unobvious.

By the way, if you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I will try my best to explain what went wrong

```
lst = [ x**2 for x in [x**2 for x in range(11)] ]
print(lst)
# outputs [0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000]
```

In order to achieve the same results without using list comprehension, what you can do is to split up into 2 lists. The nested list and the output list.

```
lst2= []
nestedlist = []
for x in range(11):
  nestedlist.append(x**2)
for x in nestedlist:
  x = x**2
  lst2.append(x)

print(lst2)
# outputs [0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000]
```

Notice how in the list comprehension the inner list is iterated first before the the outer list. Same logic applies to this "split up" version.

The reason why doing something like the following: is **WRONG**

```
lst2= []
nestedlist = []
for x in range(11):
  nestedlist.append(x**2)
  for x in nestedlist:
    lst2.append(x**2)

print(lst2)
#outputs [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 16, 0, 1, 16, 81, 0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000]
```

Is because when you are doing the following,

```
  for x in nestedlist:
    lst2.append(x**2)
```

What you are actually doing is applying `**2` the **LENGTH** of the list. Hence outputting for example [0,1] to [0,1,0,1], not the elements in the list.

I guess list comprehension is smart in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst =[]
tmp = []
for x in range(11):
    tmp.append(x**2)

for x in tmp:
    lst.append(x**w)
```